# IComparer problem

Tags: c#

Purpose: To have multiple options to sort using properties of my class . 
I managed to sort using samAccountName using Comparable but failed to correctly implement IComparer. But know I am getting an error specified below.

*Error:Does not implement interface member System.Collections.Icomparer*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ActiveDirectory
{
    public class sortLastName : IComparer
    {
        int IComparer.CompareTo(Employee oEmployee, Employee oEmployee2)
        {
            return String.Compare(oEmployee.lastName, oEmployee2.lastName);
        }
        public static IComparer sortYearAscending()
        {
            return (IComparer)new sortLastName();
        }

    }
//The code works great when I make a call like 
// List<Employee> x = new List<Employee>();
// x.sort();// sorts by samAccountName
// Now I would like to figure out how to sort by lastName and still be able to sort by 
//samAccountName if necceaary. 
    public class Employee :IComparable
    {
        //default sort order
        public int CompareTo(object oEmployee)
        {
            Employee emp1 = (Employee)oEmployee;
            return String.Compare(this.samAccountName, emp1.samAccountName);
        }



        public string lastName
        {
            get;
            set;

        }

          public string samAccountName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to implement a method named "[Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx)" not "CompareTo" for your `sortLastName`-class implementing [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx)

then you can sort by `x.Sort` with this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx):

```
x.Sort(new sortLastName());
```

this is the implementation you should use:

```
public class sortLastName : IComparer<Employee>
{
    public int Compare(Employee oEmployee, Employee oEmployee2)
    {
        return String.Compare(oEmployee.lastName, oEmployee2.lastName);
    }
}
```

(Note I didn't change the name because you wouldn't see the context any more but sortLastName is no good name for a comparer)

Comment: EmployeeLastNameComparer or CompareEmployeeByLastName

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea what your `IComparer` implementation is for.

You should probably implement `IComparable<T>` instead of non-generic `IComparable`, but whatever.

Either way, incorporate the sort order you want into your `CompareTo` function.  For example:

```
public int CompareTo(object oEmployee)
{
    Employee e = (Employee)oEmployee;
    int cmp = 0;
    if ((cmp = string.Compare(this.samAccountName, e.samAccountName) != 0)
        return cmp;
    if ((cmp = string.Compare(this.lastName, e.lastName) != 0)
        return cmp;

    // ...any other properties you care to compare by

    // else it's a tie:
    return cmp;
}
```

Then this should work correctly with `List<T>.Sort`, since the default comparer will look for an implementation of `IComparable` on your type.

EDIT:  On a re-read, I'm not sure whether you want to sort by one criteria, the other, or both.  But I'll leave this answer in for posterity in case you want to sort by both.

Comment: are you sure you understood the question? As I read this he wants to compare by samAccountName but have the option to sort by LastName as well - your solution would sort by AccountName and then by LastName - but as educated guess: the AccountNames will be unique so this doesn't make much sense at all

Comment: No, I might have misinterpreted it.  I added a note to the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

IComparer. Compare takes two object as argument. You don't use that signature in class sortLastName.  There also is a generic version, if that's the interface You want...

IComparer : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: The generic version is needed as input to List<T>.Sort(...)   See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You dont need IComparer or IComparable to achieve this at all.

```
List<Employee> sortedByLastname = lstEmployee.OrderBy(x => x.LastName);
```

Comment: The example he gave as a use case was sorting a list in-place, which is a reasonable thing to want to do.

Comment: You are correct. But that wasnt my question.I know I could have List<Employee> newList = oEmployee.OrderBy(x => x.samAccountName).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Implementation: 
//suppose that this fill out the list with employees.
//After your suggestions this is what I ended up doing.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            populatecboAdUsers();
        }
public void populatecboAdUsers()
        {
            List oEmployee = manager.getAllEmployees();
            //oEmployee.Sort();//uses the default compare by samAccountName

            IComparer myComparer = new Employee.compareEmployeeByLastName();
            oEmployee.Sort(myComparer.Compare);
            foreach (var x in oEmployee)
            {

                cboAdUsers.Items.Add(x.lastname);
                Console.WriteLine(x.lastname);

       }
}//end of Form1:form class

//new class below
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;


namespace ActiveDirectory
{


    public class Employee :IComparable
    {
        public class compareEmployeeByLastName : IComparer
        {
            int IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)
            {
                Employee emp1 = (Employee)x;
                Employee emp2 = (Employee)y;
                return String.Compare(emp1.lastname, emp2.lastname);
            }
        }
        //default sort order
        public int CompareTo(object oEmployee)
        {
            Employee emp1 = (Employee)oEmployee;
            return String.Compare(this.samAccountName, emp1.samAccountName);
        }


        public string firstName 
        { 
            get; set; 
        }

        public string lastName
        {
            get;
            set;

        }

        public string commonName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string department
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string distinguishedName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string employeeID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string samAccountName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string email
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public UserPrincipalExtension oUserPrincipalExtension
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }



}
```