# How to implement IComparer in C# for an interface

Tags: c#, icomparer

I have an interface named `IEmployee`. I need to implement the IComparer to the implementation of my interface.

Here is my code,

```
interface IEmployee
  {

      String Name {get;set;}
      DateTime DOB {get;set;}
  }
```

I have created a child class for this like

```
class Employee
  {

      String Name {get;set;}
      DateTime DOB {get;set;}
  }
```

Now i need to implement the IComparer to this, and in my `Main` i want to get the copmarer like

```
IComparer<IEmployee> comparerobject= // The comparer from the class.
```

And using this `comparer` i need to sort the collection of `employee` based on their names, like

```
var employees = new IEmployee[]{new Employee("....."),....}
Array.Sort<IEmployee>(employees , comparer);
```

Comment: for the love of <deity> please don't prefix you classes with 'c'

Comment: @Anonymous, probably this line `Please help me to doi this`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IComparer problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234128/icomparer-problem)

Comment: Regarding the downvotes, readers probably want you to explain what you have tried.  I didn't -1 personally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could instead implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx). Then your code could look something like:

```
interface IEmployee : IComparable
{
    String Name { get; set; }
    DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}

class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return this.Name.CompareTo(((IEmployee)obj).Name);
    }
}
```

Then you can just sort the array as follows:

```
Array.Sort<IEmployee>(employees);
```

Comment: I think you meant "You could just have your [class] implement IComparable" (i.e. not "interface").

Comment: @J0e3gan Yes, I should have worded that more carefully. The class would contain the implementation, but how would you explain it if the implementation of an interface required you also implement another interface (as in my answer above)?

Comment: No worries - was just trying to help clarify a good answer.  I guess I would say "You could just define an appropriate interface that inherits `IComparable` - e.g. `IEmployee` - and then have your class implement it."

Comment: It is interesting that even MSDN documentation on C# interfaces has muddied language in this respect - using "inherit" in [VS-2008-era documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156(v=VS.80).aspx) ("Interfaces can _inherit_ other interfaces.") and "implement" in [VS-2012-era documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156(v=vs.110).aspx) ("Interfaces can _implement_ other interfaces.") with respect to a relationship between interfaces like you outline between `IComparable` and `IEmployee`.  We just can't beat language's inherent ambiguity sometimes. :}

Answer (score 10):

you can do

```
var sorted = employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ToArray();
```

or with a comparer

```
public class EmployeeComparer : IComparer<IEmployee>
    {
        public int Compare(IEmployee x, IEmployee y)
        {
            return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
        }
    }
```

then `Array.Sort(employees, new EmployeeComparer());`

Comment: This is the best way to do this, in terms of readability - but it is slightly inefficient in that it creates an extra `IEnumerable<IEmployee>` and dynamically sized array before the final array is returned...

Comment: @Keith Nicholas : I'm aware of this way. But i need to Implement the Interface to get the comparer.

Comment: given you a comparer.....

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you want to use an `IComparer`?  You have several options other than that.

First of all, you can use a Linq query as described by @Keith.  That has some memory implications since a new `IEnumerable` must be allocated.

Perhaps your best option is to use the overload of the `Sort` method that takes in a `Comparison` object, which is just a delegate that compares two objects:

```
Array.Sort(employees, (a, b) => a.Name.CompareTo(b.Name));
```

If you really want to use `IComparer`, then you need to make a class that implements `IComparer<IEmployee>`:

```
public class EmployeeComparer : IComparer<IEmployee>
{
    public int Compare(IEmployee e1, IEmployee e2)
    {
        return e1.Name.CompareTo(e2.Name);
    }
}
```

And then use that for the `Sort` method.  You could also make `Employee` itself implement `IComparer` if you so desired, but that is strange, since then it could really just implement `IComparable`.