# How to do I use my overwriten Compare Method?

Tags: c#, compare

I want to sort data by the alphabet. I implemented IComparer<> into my class, and also overwritten the Compare Method. My Question now is how I can use this method?

Comment: Share your code please...

Comment: It is better not to put the sort into an existing class but make it a separated class.  You need to create a constructor for the list so the comparison works and then use the linq OrderBy to do the sort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using IComparer for sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336416/using-icomparer-for-sorting) and [Using IComparer<T>.Compare(T,T) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597770/using-icomparert-comparet-t-in-c-sharp) and [How to implement IComparer in C# for an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474668/how-to-implement-icomparer-in-c-sharp-for-an-interface)

Answer (score 1):

All what you need is to call on Array.Sort() giving it the array to be sorted and the an instance of your custom comparer class. Here's an example:

```
public class Car {
    ...
}

public class CarComparer : IComparer<Car> {
    public int Compare(Car x, Car y) {
        ...
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var cars = new Car[] { ... };
    var carComparer = new CarComparer();
    Array.Sort(cars, carComparer);
}
```